# JS: Should I set a var/let in a click (or equivalent) event?

Tags: javascript, events

Curious to know what and why is correct?

I'm asking because I'm never sure what to use when.

This:

```
function foo(){
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            var baq = 'baz';
        })
}
```

Or this

```
function foo(){
    var baq;
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            baq = 'baz';
        })
}
```

And also this:

```
function foo(){
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            let baq = 'baz';
        })
}
```

Or this

```
function foo(){
    let baq;
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            baq = 'baz';
        })
}
```

Comment: All depends on what you want to do

Comment: Can you please explain, I'm never sure what to use when.

Comment: @BobvanLuijt it is not about which is correct since all are correct. They have different meanings in terms of variable scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends!!

scenario 1:
change variables depending upon events

```
    function foo(){
    var baq;// to avoid scope conflicts
        baq = 0;
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            baq++;//increment baq with click event
        })
}
```

scenario 2:
dealing with context

```
    function foo(){
    var baq;// to avoid scope conflicts
        baq = $(this);
    $('.bar')
        .click(function(){
            baq = $(this);
        })
}
```

i can't imagine all cases.but there is a good video on youtube about this.
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBwoFkRjZvE)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first two pieces of code.

Let's say you click on an item with classname `bar`, and when you do this, you want to set `baq` to the value of baz, and that's it.*You aren't really concerned with the variable `baq` after the click occurs.* Here the variable is **local** in its scope.

```
function foo(){
$('.bar')
    .click(function(){
        var baq = 'baz';
    })}
```

Now, maybe you are concerned about variable baq. Let's say you're building a pizza?`Baq` is first a string variable `" "`.

In the first function, you add cheese,some people may not.So i say `baq="Cheese"`. In the next selection, let's say there is a class `"vegetables"`.When someone clicks on a vegetable, I add a veggie,
`baq=baq+"mushrooms"`. Next, there is a class `"meat"`.Similarly, so on.

In the essence, when I want to **reuse** `baq`, i use the following, where the variable is `global` in it's scope.Click on the cheese and mushrooms in the 
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gtkt472h/)

```
function foo(){
var baq;
$('.bar')
    .click(function(){
        baq = 'baz';
    })}
```

For information about usage of `let`,check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4759033)